# После добавления столбца в SQL выходить ошибка

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Дали старый проект на C# .NET 2.0, так же со старым ASP.NET. Не меняя код, добавил 1 столбец в таблицу с компаниями. После этого вылезла ошибка: Ошибка преобразования значения nvarchar "/information/" в тип данных int.
Он пытается то ли URL то ли страницу преобразовать в int
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Какие файлы нужно отредактировать и из-за чего данная ошибка может возникать?

Comment: Этому дотнету 15 лет, кто ж вспомнит, как тогда код писался. Где-то там SQL запросы есть к базе, видимо, которые перестали работать после ее миграции. SQL знаете, вот его в коде и ищите, там наверняка что-то типа старого ADO.NET используется. В каких методах исключение, вам в трассировке стека написано, которые без приставки `System` - в вашем проекте, остальные в дотнете.

Answer (score 1):

Связался со старыми разработчиками, оказывается была такая ошибка ранее.

Для её решения создавался сценарий, который удалял, а потом создавал таблицу ("Drop and Create"). То есть, обновляем все представления в БД (drop and create).